# NotSupportedException "The Uri prefix is not recognized" in console application

Tags: c#, uri

I am trying to read metrics from an true type file (ttf) by using a net-framework console application.

"Unfortunately" following code works:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{                      
    if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
    {
        var parser = new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority);
        UriParser.Register(parser, "pack", -1);
    }

    var fontUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TestConsole;component/cmmi10.ttf");

    Console.WriteLine(fontUri.Scheme);
    Console.ReadKey(); 

    var glyph = new GlyphTypeface(fontUri);

    Console.WriteLine(glyph.FontUri.ToString());

    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Unfortunately, because as soos as i comment out the first `Console.ReadKey();` I get an **NotSupportedException** with message "The Uri prefix is not recognized".

I discovered this behaviour by chance while searching for a solution for this NotSupportedException. So I tried to show several Uri properties in the console in order to understand which part of it was wrong. It turned out to be the "pack" scheme, which is apparently wpf-specific and must be registered explicitly in a console application.

While there are several similiar questions on this very exception, I didn't found an explenation that could connect the `Console.ReadKey()` method to a not found uri prefix.

I tracked the place in the source code where this exception is thrown:

[https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs.html#4a9454016805ca53][1] - Line 203

Aparently, this is the method where the prefix for the "pack" scheme is verified. But this can not be the problem, as the scheme is already registered. How could that relate to the out-commented `Console.ReadKey()`?

Comment: Is this font embedded in the app? It looks like you are trying to read a WPF/XAML style URI but it is in a console app? Does it actually print out valid data when you have the read keys commented?

Comment: @RonBeyer: It is only a "Resource". It print's valid data till first readkey is removed. The file origins from an a wpf application. I tried to retrieve some metrics with a console application, because that is easier. You can get the ttf-file here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf